# Changing The Font Of Text Area

Tags: html, textarea

I think this is a simple and a silly question. I have included a text area in my html script.

Is it possible to change the default font of the text area?

The default one doesn't look good. I hope there is a way to change it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, using the CSS [`font-family` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-family-prop), just like any other element.

The W3C has a [CSS tutorial](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#CSS) as does [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics)

Comment: For whatever reason, this didn't work for me when applying the font-family using a CSS class in Chrome. The only way I could get it to work was to set the textarea's CSS specifically to font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit; then applying the class that had font-family set.

Answer (score 20):

You can just open your css file and write code as mentioned below

```
textarea  
{  
   font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;  
   font-size: 12px;   
}
```

By following the above procedure, you can change the default property of any HTML tag you want.

Answer (score 8):

And the shortcut lazy version (not recommended):

```
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" 
     style="font-family:Times New Roman;color:#003399;white-space:pre-wrap">Put your text here</textarea>
```

Comment: Why is this not recommended?

Comment: You should use Cascading Style Sheets along with the class or ID selectors rather than an inline style attribute or font tag, which may be deprecated.

Comment: @MateusRibeiro _You_ might hate CSS but if you're trying to do something like implementing CSP for creating secure websites then you'll end up creating unnecessary problems for yourself if you use inline styles. Also, inline styles make reusability and maintainability more difficult.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the font short hand version

```
textarea
{
    font: 12px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

The values:

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family;
```