# How to format or style text in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, textarea

I need to create a textarea to display data, it should looks like this(expected behavior):

[image]

This is my current UI (current behavior):

[image]

This is my HTML:

```
<textarea disabled class="bgYellow" rows="6">{{text1}}</textarea>
```

This is my Typescript Code:

```
  invoiceNo = '1000799758-00';
  status = 'Spark';
  palletLP = '';
  needAudit = 'NO';

  text1 = 'Invoice No.:  ' + this.invoiceNo + '\n' +
          'Status:  ' + this.status + '\n' +
          'Pallet LP:  ' + this.palletLP + '\n' +
          'Audit?:  ' + this.needAudit;
```

Can any one tell me how Can I make this Invoice No. Label align to left, data align to right.
It is like Bootstrap grid style, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Looks like you are not using a monospace font for your textarea.. textarea doesn't have any other formatting options other than using Tabs & spaces.  Does this need to be a textarea?..

Comment: I used font-family: monospace; I just removed to make the html code in one line..Yeah, our project is using Angular to mimic a very old java application...Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the single backtick :

```
 text1 = `
Invoice No, : 1
Status      : 2
Pallet LP   : 3
...         : 4`
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aewrtv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

change your code into

```
text1 =  ' Invoice No.: ' + this.invoiceNo + '\n' +
      '      Status: ' + this.status + '\n' +
      '   Pallet LP: ' + this.palletLP + '\n' +
      '      Audit?: ' + this.needAudit;
```

And then change the text area to use a terminal (fixed width font) using css will hopefully fix the problem.

[Changing The Font Of Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094981/changing-the-font-of-text-area)